How to show the selected slug value as selected in <select> dropdown in Svelte
I navigate to this page with the slug param deckId, I have a dropdown menu that is bound to deckId.
My problem is that when navigating to the page or refreshing the selected option disappears. The variable deckId is defined but not shown as selected.
It worked if I added this to the code,
deckId = $page.params.deckId;
const selectElement = document.querySelector('select');
selectElement.value = deckId;

I was however told that that solution is not ideal and that there is a better way to do it. What is the better way?
import { page } from '$app/stores';
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
import { Jumper } from 'svelte-loading-spinners';
export let data;
let deckId = $page.params.deckId;
async function handleChangeID(event) {
        goto('/homePage/studyDeck/' + event.target.value + '/' + cardStatus + '/');
        await getCards();
        showBack = false;
    }

{#await data.decks}
                <span><Jumper /></span>
            {:then decks}
                <h2 class="font-bold mb-2 text-center text-primary-900 my-auto mr-2">Deck</h2>
                <select
                    class="border border-gray-300 p-2 w-full h-auto rounded text-primary-900 dark:text-primary-400 bg-background-0 dark:bg-primary-60 mr-4"
                    bind:value={deckId}
                    on:change={handleChangeID}
                >
                    {#each decks as deck}
                        <option value={deck.value}>{deck.label}</option>
                    {/each}
                </select>
            {/await}

This is where the decks are coming from (+layout.js):
export async function load({ fetch }) {
    
    async function getDecks() {
        const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3001/Deck';
        try {
            const response = await fetch(API_URL, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                credentials: 'include'
            });
            const data = await response.json();

            return data.map((item) => ({
                value: item.deckId,
                label: item.deckName
            }));
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    }

    return {
        decks: getDecks(),

    };
}

I've tried multiple variations of this:
selected={deck.value === deckId}

which then looks like this:
<option value={deck.value} selected={deck.value === deckId}>{deck.label}</option>

This sadly didn't change anything

You could try making a new, reactive variable based on deckId. Check out this REPL where someone does this. It would look like this:
let deckId = $page.params.deckId;
$: selectedDeckId = deckId;

<option value={deck.value}
        selected={deck.value === selectedDeckId}>
  {deck.label}
</option>

Otherwise, to at least make your workaround a bit cleaner, you could bind the element. Svelte offers the bind:this directive for this, which is preferred over document.querySelector. It would look like this:
import { onMount } from "svelte";

let elSelect;

onMount(() => {
    elSelect.value = deckId;
});

<select bind:this={elSelect}>...</select>

Note the use of onMount to reference the DOM element only when everything is loaded (before mounting, the value is undefined). Depending on where exactly you put the document.querySelector('select'), it might still have worked, because the DOM was already loaded. But to avoid race conditions, you should only reference the DOM after making sure that the component is mounted.
